# Chai - Expect an object to have deep property of an array ignore order

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, chai

I need to check if the `payment` has a property named `transactions` with expected values:

```
expect(payment).to.have.deep.property('transactions', [
    TRANSACTION_ID_1,
    TRANSACTION_ID_2,
]);
```

As the order of `transactions` is not specified, the test doesn't pass all the time.

How can I solve the problem without changing the test structure?

Note: I've found [`deep-equal-in-any-order`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal-in-any-order) plugin, but it seems it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through array and check if it includes each item.

```
[TRANSACTION_ID_1, TRANSACTION_ID_2].forEach(id => {
  expect(payment).to.have.deep.property('transactions').that.includes(id);
});
```

If you need to check `transactions` is unordered array of expected IDs, then check for the length as well.

```
expect(payment).to.have.deep.property('transactions').that.has.lengthOf(2);
```

When `transactions` has all of the expected ids and has same length of expected ids, then it equals to the expected ids when ordered properly.

Comment: I wonder if there is any solution that doesn't require a `loop`

Comment: I doubt if there is. You could sort both of the arrays and assert too.